# untime - Template processing error: "No mapping defined for spring framework tags

Tags: freemarker, weblogic12c

My current development environment is java 6, spring framework 3.2, weblogic 10.3.6 and using Freemarker templates. Everything is working fine in current environment, don't see any runtime issues while browsing pages.

IDE: eclipse kepler 4.3 and I am running weblogic server from eclipse IDE. My deployment assembly is from m2e plugin that comes with kepler.

Now I am upgrading to latest Weblogic 12.1.2 and java 7. I am able to successfully build, deploy and publish the module but while accessing pages, I see runtime issues with freemarker templates.

There is a related issue discussed in forum for tomcat deployment wherein solution is to add spring-security-taglibs to pom file and place spring-security-taglibs.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. But that does not work for me.

Greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue. I see many freemarker template exception related postings but not solution.

Below is the runtime error, I am seeing.

2013-09-23 14:16:30,696 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR  freemarker.runtime  - Template processing error: "No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/tags"

The problematic instruction:

### Java backtrace for programmers:

freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/tags

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like FreeMarker's JSP extension haven't discovered the TLD file that contains `<uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags</uri>`. It looks for it under `/WEB-INF/*.tld` and `/WEB-INF/lib/*.{jar,zip}/META-INF/*.tld`. If it's not there and you don't want to put it there, you can map that URL to the TLD file location in the `web.xml` with the `taglib` element.

Comment: You are right, I do not have explicitly *.tld file copied to /WEB-INF or META-INF. My pom.xml file has dependency defined and I do see it in deployment assembly. I am using in my .ftl as "<#assign spring=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags"]>
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>.

Comment: So where is it in the deployed application? Not under `/WEB-INF/lib/*.{jar,zip}/META-INF/*.tld`?

Comment: We have not specifically deployed *.tld files under WEB-INF. It was never needed until this weblogic upgrade to 12c. Everything worked fine for weblogic 10.3.6 with dependencies in pom and accessing url in freemarker as "<#assign spring=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags"]>
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>
<#assign c=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"]/>
". I added spring related tld files under WEB-INf. Now I am getting error for jstl as freemarker TemplateModelException: No mapping defined for http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.

Comment: As far as I see the only places where FreeMarker looks for the TLD-s are those that I have listed. So earlier it had to be at some of those places. And I don't think you had to deploy them specifically, as if you have deployed spring-youknowwhat.jar (I don't know Spring...) into WEB-INF/lib, it probably contains the TLD. Weren't those jar-s moved to higher maybe? Just a tip...

Comment: BTW, what are you using JSTL core in a FreeMarker tempalte for? (I'm also not sure why the Spring tags are JSP, when Spring had FreeMarker directives for exposing Spring functionality, but I don't know Spring much.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is existing code that I am upgrading to weblogic 12, don't know rationale behind using jsp with freemarker but it is used. I got rid off JSTL related errors also by placing required tld files under WEB-INF. I am getting errors related to spring security tags now, tried applying same logic, placing needed tld file under WEb-INF. This time it did not work for spring security tag. I still have "no mapping filr found for spring security tags" in freemarker templates.

Comment: I can't know what's up with Spring security specifically (is the URL in the TLD exactly the same). Maybe the easiest is if you debug into it. OTOH it's stil strange that you have to put TLD-s directly under WEB-INF; aren't the TLD-s present in `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar/META-INF/`?

Comment: No, it is not copied under META-INF directory. I figured out, there was a conflict in spring.tld file. I resolved it and now putting under WEB-INF works fine. It is strange for me that I have to do anything with tld files, it is suppose to work once you specify dependencies in pom file. I don't understand how upgrade from weblogic 10.3.6 to weblogic 12c would cause this issue.

Comment: Since it works, the class pointed by `tag-class` in the TLD is found too. So where's that class file? The TLD should be in the same `jar` (under `META-INF`).

Answer (score 0):

Was this issue ever resolved?  If i deploy the WAR externally from WL admin console, everything works fine and no freemarker template error. I am running into similar errors when deploying WAR from Eclipse (Mars) , Weblogic 12.2.1. Workaround is to copy TLDs to WEB-INF and then deploy from eclipse I get no errors. However, there shouldn't be a need to copy these TLDs as they are in the JAR files under WEB-INF/lib.