# Spring boot freemarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I get this exception when I try to import JspTaglibs in a spring boot application.

> freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: No mapping defined for
>   http://www.springframework.org/tags/form

Hear is part of my ftl file, when I try to import it.

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"] />
```

Get this problem only when starting the application as a spring boot app, works if deployed on standalone tomcat with a war file.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985142/untime-template-processing-error-no-mapping-defined-for-spring-framework-tag

Comment: when I check into the jar, id look like this lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar --> META-INF/spring-form.tld , so no WEB-INF directory. is that the problem ?

Comment: I have also try to move the tld file to my project so I have it like this WEB-INF/spring-form.tld , but still same problem

Comment: Tld can be placed anywhere (you can develop own or reuse one from jar), but you need configure your web-server by placing params to WEB-INF/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the code below to give templates path.

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Bean(name ="freemarkerConfig") 
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() {
           FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
           configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("**classpath:mail**/");
           Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
           map.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
           configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(map);
      return configurer;
    }
}
```